# How to count occurrences and update dictionary value?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am iterating through a database column

I need to create a dictionary that updates certain values of certain keys if a criterion is met.

For example

```
The first iteration is: 'apples'
The dictionary should be {'apples': 1}

The second iteration is: 'peers'
The dictionary should be {'apples': 1, 'peers': 1}

The third iteration is: 'apples'
The dictionary should be {'apples': 2, 'peers': 1}
```

I apologise for the basic explanation. Its the best way ( I think ) to communicate what I want, because I don't know how to code this.

I need this to be in a dictionary because this operation is deep into a nested for loop structure

THE GOAL:

Is to get the iteration that appears most

DESIRED OUTCOME:

```
mostListed = 'apples'
```

I am new to python, if I am missing something obvious I am very open to learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Without defaultdict

You can use the following code:

```
d = {}
for iteration in ['first', 'second', 'third']:
    value = input(f'The {iteration} iteration is:')
    if value in d:
        d[value] += 1
    else:
        d[value] = 1

print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
The first iteration is:apples
The second iteration is:peers
The third iteration is:apples
{'apples': 2, 'peers': 1}
```

### Using defaultdict

You can create a `defaultdict` which default value is `0` as follows:

```
from _collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for iteration in ['first', 'second', 'third']:
    value = input(f'The {iteration} iteration is:')
    d[value] += 1

print(dict(d))
```

**Output**

```
The first iteration is:apples
The second iteration is:peers
The third iteration is:apples
{'apples': 2, 'peers': 1}
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for! Saved the day

Answer (score 4):

Using `Counter()` from `collections`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l = ["apples", "pears", "apples"]
>>> Counter(l)
Counter({'apples': 2, 'pears': 1})
```

Making it work for your case goes for example like:

```
from collections import Counter

list_ = []

for item in ["first", "second", "third"]:
    input_value = input(f"{item} iteration: ")
    list_.append(input_value)
count = Counter(list_)
print(count) # output: Counter({'apples': 2, 'pears': 1})
print(count.most_common(1)) # output: [('apples', 2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to the already numerous answers for its clarity

```
from collections import Counter

values = ['apples', 'peers', 'apples']

Counter(values).most_common(1)

>>> [('apples', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
my_list = ['apples', 'apples', 'peers', 'apples', 'peers']
new_dict = {}

for i in my_list:
    if i in new_dict:
        new_dict[i] += 1
    else:
        new_dict[i] = 1

print(new_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the values of a key in a dictionary by doing

```
if 'apples' in dict:
    dict['apples'] += 1
else:
    dict['apples'] = 1
```

and you can find the key with the maximum value by something like this:

```
most_listed = max(dict, key=lambda k: dict[k])
```